# ORA error in wso2 apim-analytics server

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

1) I'm getting below error in wso2carbon logs when I try to configure wso2 apim-analytics(2.1) server with Oracle DB(12c version). I have tried with ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc7.jar in lib folder but still error is there.

error:
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication 
    protocol

2)  Is there any REST api available for wso2 apim-analytics similar to DAS server to extract data?

**full error:**

ERROR 
   {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask} -  Error while executing 
   the scheduled task for the script: APIM_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SCRIPT 
   {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask}

org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.exception.AnalyticsExecutionException: 
   Exception in executing query create temporary table APILastAccessSummaryData 
   using CarbonJDBC options (dataSource "WSO2AM_STATS_DB", tableName 
   "API_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SUMMARY",    schema "tenantDomain STRING ,
   apiPublisher STRING ,    api STRING ,    version STRING ,    userId STRING ,
   context STRING ,    max_request_time LONG ",    primaryKeys 
   "tenantDomain,apiPublisher,api"    )
              at

org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQueryLocal(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:764)
           at

org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQuery(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:721)
           at

org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeQuery(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:201)
           at

org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeScript(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:151)
          at 
  org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask.execute(AnalyticsTask.java:60)
           at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:

ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

thanks,
Santosh

Comment: paste the full log error

Comment: added full error above in question

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue identified in Oracle, and the workaround is : to set SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in the $crs_home/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file. [1]

[1] https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/UCMDB-and-UD-Practitioners-Forum/ORA-28040-No-matching-authentication-protocol/m-p/253403